# Nuxt + Azure AD + Laravel API

Tags: laravel, azure-active-directory, nuxt.js

I found Nuxt Azure AD authentication which helps get JWT token from Azure. Nuxt app will fetch data from Laravel API. How to implement API auth validation. Every API has User model so Azure AD response should be validated on API side and assign specific user.

[Azure AD response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIHic.png)

Comment: What you provided is the token of `graph api`.

Comment: It's decoded JWT using npm jwt-decode. From Azure I get Bearier token which can be decoded to this json.

Comment: I know that your token has been decoded. I mean your token is used to call ms graph api.

Comment: So, I have to use this token and validate it in back-end?

Comment: If you are not calling ms graph api, then the token may not be suitable for you.

Comment: Before when application was only on laravel-mix I was using @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client to authenticate azure user and assign local user. Now application was split to front-end nuxtjs and back-end works only like API. So the back-end still holds user information with azure unique id (691f6936-19c2....). I can't find answer how implement azure authentication to front-end and back-end which works together.

Comment: I assume that you have no idea about how to make your Laravel API knows if the incoming requests is legal and stand for whom. If so, I can share my ideas when developing js frontend app + java backend app. I used msal.js in the frontend which provides sign in module and offers access token for calling api. I added a filter in my backend app which validate all the incoming requests and check if the requests have Bearer token in the request and have valid scope. It uses jwt decode library and get the claims in the token. I can get user infor contained in the token too and know represents whom.

Comment: Have you exposed the api in Azure?

Comment: I have, but still unsure how it should be used

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it to end the thread, thanks！

Answer (score 1):

At present, you have registered an application representing the api in Azure AD, and have exposed the api for the api application. Next, you need to register another client application representing the Nuxt application, and then add the **client application** to **api application**.

[image]

Next, go to the client application.

- Under **'API permissions'** click on **'Add permission'**, then click on the
  **'My APIs'** tab.
- Find your api application and select the appropriate scope.
- Click 'Add permissions'.
- Grant **admin consent** for your APIs.

[image]

Then, I use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to get the user token.

1.Request an authorization code in the browser.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client app client id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://{api app client id}/{scope name}
&state=12345
```

2.Redeem token.

[image]

Parse the token：

[image]

Parse the token and you will see that the `aud` claim is the client id of your api application. At the same time, the token also contains user information.